# Getting the text value of the text field and passing that value to a label through a button click

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield

My label doesn't show any after I clicked the button. Here is my .h and .m files

.h file

```
@interface TrialViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *myTextField;

@end
```

.m file

```
@implementation TrialViewController

@synthesize myTextField = _myTextField;

@synthesize myLabel = _myLabel;

 -(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {

    self.myLabel.text = self.myTextField.text;

 }
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint and inspect _myLabel and _myTextField pointers, they might be not connected.

Comment: Maybe use strong instead of weak?

Comment: @Davyd Thanks! :) _myTextField isn't connected that's why.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow (SO)! Please accept answers when someone helps you in order to show the correct answer and reward them with added reputation for their help!

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause for this is not having either the outlets or the actions connected.  Can you check that in the xib file / storyboard?  Select the TrialViewController and select the connections inspector on the right (little round arrow).

Comment: Ok, but then I don't know which is to connect to what. :(

Answer (score 0):

When you use weak as a declared property, some other strong reference must be maintained to that variable or it will automatically be set to nil.  If you declare it as strong, it will keep the reference until you release it by setting it to nil (typical in `viewDidUnload`).

Change these line:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *myTextField;
```

to this:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *myTextField;
```

and add this to your `viewDidUnload` method:

```
_myLabel     = nil;
_myTextField = nil;
```